# Tkinter doesn't work with Python 3.5

Tags: tkinter

I have tried all the hello world for tkinter and python 3.5 on my PC 64 bit Windows 8 but it doesn't work...

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.myButton = Button(self, text='Button Label')
        self.myButton.grid()

    root = Tkinter.Tk()

    root.title('Frame w/ Button')
    root.geometry('200x200')

    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This code gives me the error `NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined`

I am grateful for any help,
Alain

Comment: is your file named "tkinter.py"?

Comment: The traceback must have said 'Tkinter', not 'Tk'.  Please copy and paste instead of typing what you remember.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your code you write

```
from tkinter import *
```

Then you use

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
```

Why didn't you try

```
root = Tk()
```

?

Because you are importint everything from `tkinter` you do not need to use the module to access `Tk()`. And you have a typo too in your mentioned line: the module's name starts with a lowercase `t`.

Comment: Name 'tkinter' is also not defined after the * import, so 'tkinter.Tk()' is not an option.  Your change to 'root = Tk()' is the only way.