# Tkinter root widget won't initialize with python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, anaconda, tk-toolkit

I've just installed Anaconda and tries to run a script that worked fine before when just using Python 2.7. Now, I cannot initialize a root widget in tkinter. I've tried several expressions but none work so far. For example:

1.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
```

2.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
```

which I guess should work according to the answer in: [Tkinter doesn't work with Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229303/tkinter-doesnt-work-with-python-3-5) which says that I don't need to call the module (tkinter) when importing everything from it.

Anyway, what I get is the following message:

```
2016-04-28 17:58:16.168 python[1808:507] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a5270d0
2016-04-28 17:58:16.172 python[1808:507] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-04-28 17:58:16.172 python[1808:507] -[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a5270d0
2016-04-28 17:58:16.172 python[1808:507] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f5d925c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8ef5ee75
```

.

.

.

```
27  python                              0x0000000100000cc4 start + 52
28  ???                                 0x0000000000000002 0x0 + 2
```

According to this question [module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk' with python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547661/module-tkinter-has-no-attribute-tk-with-python-3-5) it seems like there is a file somewhere that I'm supposed to delete.

I should also tell that I can still create use tk.Tk() directly in Terminal but when I run it in the script it won't work.

Comment: Follow `import tkinter as tk` with `print(tk.__file__)`.  On Windows, you should see something like `.../python35/Lib/tkinter/__main__.py`.

Comment: This is what I get (on my mac):
/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py
So, what do I do with that?

Comment: Drop the idea that you need to delete a file named tkinter.py (as in the answer you linked).  Next test: is the anaconda copy of tkinter/__init__.py obviously corrupt?  Try `print(dir(tk), len(dir(tk)))`.  Does it contain `Tk` and other widget classes?  I get 165 for the len (200 with 2.7) and believe it should be the same for you.  The result should be subset of names in the 2.7 list.

Comment: The error message `-[NSApplication _setup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` is Mac-specific but generic within Macs.  You might try searching for an explanation.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, I got 158 and yes, Tk is one of the classes shown in the list. It seems that your last comment is what I should focus on though...

Comment: Googled the error message and apparently it has not anything to do with tkinter but with matplotlib. Adding:
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

Answer (score 0):

I googled the error message and apparently it has not anything to do with tkinter but with matplotlib. I had no idea that was relevant for the problem. Adding:

```
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

solved the problem. I have no idea why, though.
Found the solution here: https://github.com/MTG/sms-tools/issues/29